# SetComputerNameEX returns success but computer name not changed upon restart

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, computer-name

I am trying to change the computer name of a domain computer using `SetComputerNameEx()`. The function returns success but when i restart the computer it still has the old computer name. `SetComputerNameEx()` works perfectly for non domain machines I am facing this issue only on domain computers. Am i missing something?

EDIT: I am using the following code.

```
BOOL ChangeCompName(CString csCompName)
{
    if( !SetComputerNameEx(ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,csCompName.GetBuffer()))
    {
        _tprintf(L"Failed to set Physical DNS name %d\n",GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(L"Computer name change Success\n");
    }

    if( !SetComputerNameEx(ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,csCompName.GetBuffer()))
    {
        _tprintf(L"Failed to set Physical NetBios name %d\n",GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(L"Computer name change Success\n");
    }

    return TRUE;
}
int main()
{
    if(!ChangeCompName(L"NewCompName"))
    {
        _tprintf(L"Failed to change Name.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(L"Computer name change.\n");
    }
     return 0;
}
```

I tried running the code with both administrator and system privileges. everytime i run the code it returns success but does not change the computer name. strange thing is that this code works perfectly for workgroup computer and does not work for domain computers.

Comment: One thing you are missing is a [mcve]. For all *we* know, you could have set the old name again... we cannot help you fix code that we don't know.

Comment: The  process must have administrator privileges. The computer must be a local computer.

Comment: I have added the code that i am using for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do a computer rename of a domain machine. Here is the solution if anyone needs it.

Instead of calling [SetComputerNameEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724931(v=vs.85).aspx) Just use [NetGetJoinInformation()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370423(v=vs.85).aspx) with domain administrator credential. This will rename the computer in both the domain and also locally.