# Not Changing Computer Name, but changing $env:ComputerName

Tags: c#, .net-core, unmanaged

I am trying to change the ComputerName on a windows machine. I am having a very strange result.

The Code that I'm using is:

```
public class MachineService
{
      [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      private static extern bool SetComputerNameA([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string computerName);

      [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      private static extern bool SetComputerName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string computerName);

      [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      private static extern bool SetComputerNameEx(ComputerNameFormat NameType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string computerName);


    public static bool ChangeName(string name)
    {
      var envVar = SetComputerName(name);
      var ex = SetComputerNameEx(ComputerNameFormat.ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS, name);
      return envVar && ex;
    }
}
```

It does set the Environmental Variable ComputerName but it doesn't set the name of the device. please see the images below.

[image: PowerShell ComputerName]

[image: System Name]

**EDIT**
It has changed the registry.

[image: RegEdit]

Comment: Even after a restart?

Comment: yes, I restart and it doesn't change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SetComputerNameEX returns success but computer name not changed upon restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506437/setcomputernameex-returns-success-but-computer-name-not-changed-upon-restart)

Comment: If I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setcomputernameexw) correctly you should be using `ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname` instead of `ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS`, and you should NOT call `SetComputerName` before `SetComputerNameEx`.

Comment: @SamAxe That was the issue. if you add an answer to it I will vote it up. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setcomputernameexw) correctly you should:

- be using `ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname` instead of `ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS`
- and you should NOT call `SetComputerName` before `SetComputerNameEx`